# My program stop working after I upgraded to windows 10

Tags: vb.net

The program used to do fine. Then I upgrade to Windows 10 and now I have these 2 error when running the program in Visual Studio.

> Warning 1 : Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.mshtml". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

> Error 2 : Unable to open module file "C:\Users\jim2\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb" : The system cannot find the file specified.

Basically, my code builds fine when I was in windows 7. I upgraded to windows 10 and then I got this error.

I've checked `C:\Users\jim2\AppData\Local\Temp\` folder.

There is no file `.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb`. I don't know how it happened in Windows 7. In Windows 7, before I upgraded, the program compiled just fine.

It seems that this issue is about files that are not there, but searched by project. After deleting it from project the files got created. Now, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Looks like a windows 10 issue

Comment: Try reinstalling .NET frameworks maybe?

Comment: It used to work just fine. Okay I'll reinstall .net frameworks. Works fine on windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are referencing INTERNET EXPLORER which is NOT installed into that Windows 10. The default browser is EDGE and probably the called function of IE is not present in that new browser.

Your question needs more details...

**UPDATE:**

The Microsoft.mshtml.dll file is a PIA file (from Office). You can try one of these solutions (it may vary sometimes from machine to machine):

```
1) remove Microsoft.Mshtml.dll reference from your project. 
2) Use ADD REFERENCE, NET, select the PIA file
3) In DLL properties, set the COPY LOCAL = TRUE.
```

But, if the system reports "The module is not signed", you may also try:

```
1) remove Microsoft.Mshtml.dll reference from your project. 
2) Use ADD REFERENCE and choose BROWSE.
3) Point to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies" (it depends of x32/x64 systems) and select directly the microsoft.mshtml.dll file.
4) Set the COPY LOCAL = TRUE too.
```

Comment: Internet explorer was installed when I was in Windows 7. You mean windows 10 uninstall that? My program automates internet explorer so I still need it.

Comment: I have no Windows 10 here, but I read around that IE was substituted by EDGE. And I know that EDGE is not 100% compatible with IE.

Comment: i think internet explorer is still there somewhere and I still have plenty of code automating it. So I guess I'll just want to automate internet explorer.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, it seems to be there (as Internet Explorer 11), however it´s not the default browser. Anyway, if you are facing that problem, probably your users will do the same way - be aware of this. And if you guess I helped you anyway (and I deserve, of course) please vote...  :)

Comment: I did vote. It's far from solving my problem so I can't mark you as answer

Comment: I guess I have a solution to you:  1) remove Microsoft.Mshtml.dll reference from your project.   2) Use ADD REFERENCE, NET, select the PIA file and use in properties the COPY LOCAL = TRUE.   I guess this module is really an Office module, not IE module...

Comment: Another solution (if the module is NOT signed):  1) Add Reference, Browse, point to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies" (it depends of x32/x64 systems) and select directly the microsoft.mshtml.dll file.  :)

Comment: I selected this as the answer. But please add that as an answer.

Comment: @SharenEayrs, thank you and good luck. Kindest regards from Rio de Janeiro.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to David BS answer.

It seems that the original microsoft.mshtml is gone in windows 10 and deleting and referencing it works. No need to set copy=true, etc.

I am using version 7.0.3300.0

Comment: It no longer works. I add reference and it still doesn't work.